# The degree of a primitive element

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Suppose you have a map of smooth projective irreducible curves $X \to Y$ over $\mathbb{k}$ of degree $r$. This give an extension of fields $\mathbb{k}(Y) \hookrightarrow  \mathbb{k}(X)$. The primitive element theorem says there is an element $x$ in $\mathbb{k}(X)$ such that $\mathbb{k}(X)(x) = \mathbb{k}(Y)$. Now, if you think of $x$ itself as a map $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ then $x$ has a degree, lets call it $h$.

My question is whether or not anything is known about how small $h$ can be. I am reading a paper that randomly throws in that $h<r-1$, and I can come up with examples where this is possible but in general I think not. Can a primitive element always be found with small enough degree or is this probably a condition that he is imposing?